# how to show variable or data in contentText of notification manager android

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hi I'm creating an aac player app in android, I already have notification manager like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
int icon = R.drawable.icon;
CharSequence tickerText = "Now playing...";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "txtMetaTitle";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AACPlayerActivity.this, Principal.class);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

but now im trying to put insted of normal text like **CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";** to instead show a variable in my case a metadata from shoutcast server of the stream.

i have this already to show when i open a radio station it shows logo image of station, url, title from shoutcast url with this code:

```
public void playerMetadata( final String key, final String value ) {
    TextView tv = null;

    if ("StreamTitle".equals( key ) || "icy-name".equals( key ) || "icy-description".equals( key )) {
        tv = txtMetaTitle;
    }
    else if ("icy-url".equals( key )) {
        tv = txtMetaUrl;
    }
    else return;

    final TextView ftv = tv;

    uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ftv.setText( value );
        }
    });
}
```

How I can show for example **txtMetaTitle** and implement it in the notification:

```
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "txtMetaTitle";
```

to show the metadata from shoutcast?

Thank you very much.

edit:

full code:

```
 private void start() {
        stop();

        txtMetaTitle.setText("");
        txtMetaGenre.setText("");
        txtMetaUrl.setText("");

        multiPlayer = new MultiPlayer( this, getInt( txtBufAudio ), getInt( txtBufDecode ));

        //multiPlayer.playAsync(getUrl());

        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");


        myIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("URL", getUrl());
        myIntent.putExtra("MP",new  Sharable(multiPlayer));
        startService(myIntent);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Now playing...";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
        CharSequence contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AACPlayerActivity.this, Principal.class);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
       mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

i fixed moving the notification service inside this:

```
 public void playerMetadata( final String key, final String value ) {
        TextView tv = null;

        if ("StreamTitle".equals( key ) || "icy-name".equals( key ) || "icy-description".equals( key )) {
            tv = txtMetaTitle;
        }
        else if ("icy-url".equals( key )) {
            tv = txtMetaUrl;
        }
        else return;

        final TextView ftv = tv;

        uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ftv.setText( value );
                System.out.println("Now playing..." + txtMetaTitle.getText().toString());
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                int icon = R.drawable.icon;
                CharSequence tickerText = "Now playing...";
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                CharSequence contentTitle = txtMetaTitle.getText().toString();
                CharSequence contentText = txtMetaUrl.getText().toString();
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AACPlayerActivity.this, Principal.class);
                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

                //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
               NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
               mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, if you have what you want in a textview and you want to set the ContentTitle you can use tv.getText().toString()

Comment: but i just want to show txtMetaTitle how can i do

Comment: i have that separate it in private void start() the notification manager & in public void playerMetadata the other thing i want to put in notification, how i can do? can give me an example please, thank you

Comment: Is this what you want: `CharSequence contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText();` or `CharSequence contentText = ftv.getText();`?

Comment: i tried `CharSequence contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText();` but doesnt work, shows blank space

Comment: i added the full code of notification manager

Comment: You need to use .getText().toString()

Comment: i tried `contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText().toString();` but i get blank field

Comment: im getting in log the correct metadata: 10-19 22:13:03.515: D/IcyInputStream(13206): Metadata string: StreamTitle='Hola Panama 1033 fm - Musica de Todos Los Tiempos';StreamUrl=''; also in textview shows perfect but not in notification

Comment: i added that inside `public void playerMetadata( final String key, final String value ) {`
now works, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the default notification layout, you get two lines: title and text. if you want more flexibility than that, you have to create a custom layout.

in stead of setting the title and text, instantiate a [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html),

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom);
```

and then set it into your notification object,

```
mNotification.contentView = contentView;
```

`RemoteViews` work a little differently than a normal view. you have to call methods on the `RemoteViews` object to set values into the views within. for example,

```
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_id, "Hello, world.");
```

as you can see, the types of views you can use in the layout, and the methods you can call on them are limited.

Comment: i need something more short, if u see my code how i can add what i want to show txtMetaTitle var, how i can do? thanks

Comment: you get two lines of text. you can put whatever string in those two lines you want. if you want two pieces of data in one line, concatenate the two strings to one and set it into the title or text, whatever you want. `String text = myValue1 + ":" + myValue2;`

Comment: for example i tried  `CharSequence contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText();` but doesnt work, shows blank space i just want to show that var txtMetaTitle but i cant :(

Comment: if u see my code playerMetadata in that part i get the metadata of shoutcast url so i set into textviews thats works but now i want to set that same but into my notification manager

Comment: i have this `private TextView txtMetaTitle;` so i set the metadata in a textview already, my problem is how set that same metadata but in my notification

Comment: then you have a bug. try setting a fake string into the contentText and see if that works

Comment: try this: `contextText = txtMetaTitle.getText().toString;`

Comment: what u mean how can i fix that

Comment: i tried `contentText = txtMetaTitle.getText().toString();` but same blank space

Comment: i added that inside `public void playerMetadata( final String key, final String value ) {`
now works, thanks very much.